# WPF with 2 top level windows goes to start screen when 1 closes

Tags: wpf, windows-10, tablet

We have an app that shows a splash screen which shows some data so we have a custom splash screen. Also because of historic reasons all app initialization happens on the UI thread, so my solution for that was to show the splash screen in a separate STA thread.

```
private void ShowSplashScreen()
{
    var mainDispatcher = Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher;

    var splashScreenThread = new Thread(() =>
    {
        new SplashScreen().Show();

        _splashScreenThreadDispatcher = Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher;
        Dispatcher.Run();
    });
    splashScreenThread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
    splashScreenThread.Start();
}

private void CloseSplashScreen()
{
    _splashScreenThreadDispatcher.InvokeShutdown();
}
```

And then when initialization is done this runs

```
var mw = new MainWindow();
Application.Current.MainWindow = mw;

mw.Show();

CloseSplashScreen();

mw.Activate();
```

This works fine in normal desktop mode => the main window shows, the splash screen closes and the main window is visible.
However when I switch windows to tablet mode and launch the app from the start screen, when the main window shows it only flashes and goes to background again and it shows the start screen.
If I don't close the splash then all is still visible, but that's not an option of course.

I tried various things already with topmost, different orders of calling me.Show(), mw.Activate(), me.Focus(), setting focus in Closing handler of splash screen, but nothing seems to work. 
Any ideas on how this can be fixed? In production the app is only used on tablets so it's a must have for us.

Regards
Stan

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by using a popup instead of a window for the splash screen. A popup does not require an owner or parent so it's possible to use it, and when the popup is closed the start screen doesn't go in front of the main window.